# How to use {est+} field?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

~Emacs 2.4.1 under Linux.

I would like to use the {est+} feature of column views as documented [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-attributes.html).

I customized 
`org-columns-default-Format` to be like this: (see last field)

```
%50ITEM %TODO %3PRIORITY %TAGS %CLOCKSUM_T(tod) %CLOCKSUM(sum) %5EST{est+}
```

And a property
:EST: 1-2

But when I try to activate column view in agenda, I get an error:
wrong type: sequencep, 0

I tried different format for est: (I'm not sure about syntax of the {est+} property btw?)
:EST: 1-2
:EST: 1:00-2:00
:EST: 1.0-1.1 
:EST: 1d/2d

From what I gather in [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-12/msg00435.html) thread, the correct syntax is 2-4, but that hasn't worked.

In [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-12/msg00426.html) thread it appears someone has the same issue as me (Dec 2014) but it's not clear if the issue was solved or not.

If I replace `%5EST{est+}` with   `%5EST{:}` and only use single digits or time (20:20), then column view works. But it's not quite what I want.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

There has been a bug reported and fixed last December.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/93505/focus=93514

Comment: Thank you for posting the link. It doesn't seem to load for me. Was there any progress made on fixing it?